# XSLT - Looping through XML to find child nodes with a specific value

Tags: xml, loops, templates, for-loop, xslt

Been a reader on here for many years, but this is my first ever post!

I have an XML document that I want to transform and sort.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>

    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Anton</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Large</DEPARTMENT>
            <DEPARTMENT>Medium</DEPARTMENT>
            <DEPARTMENT>Small</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Bill</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Large</DEPARTMENT>
            <DEPARTMENT>Small</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>

</ROOT>
```

In short what I want to do is pull out the full name of a user where any of there department nodes contain small.

Regards,
-Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what format you wanted the output in (HTML, text, XML...)

This wil match any `ROW` that has a `GROUPS` containing a `DEPARTMENT` with the text `Small` (case sensitive), and then display the `FULLNAME`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

        <xsl:template match="ROOT">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[GROUPS[DEPARTMENT[text() = 'Small']]]" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ROW">
            <xsl:value-of select="FULLNAME"/><br/>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank's Steve, that's exactly what i'm looking for! and sorry! should have mentioned I was looking for the output to be HTML. Thanks again! :)